# Is there a trim control / widget in OS X a la the video trimmer widget?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-controls

In a charting `UIView`, I would like the user to be able to start with the whole dataset and then use a trimming control similar to that used when trimming video in the Photos app:

[image: video trim control]

That is, two handles that can be dragged in and out, translucent panes on either side to indicate "out of range", and delegate called for "editing finished" when you tap within the "in range" area.

I don't see anything promising in Interface Builder, but it's complex enough that I'd like to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Have you find any control for video trimmer?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, there are several trimmer components on Github.

I have made one myself that you can find here: https://github.com/prynt/PryntTrimmerView

The overall idea is the following:

1. Use an `AVAssetGenerator` to generate thumbnails of the video.
2. When you load the asset, load those thumbnails in a `UIScrollView`
3. Put some controls on top of that scrollView
4. Add pan gestures to control those views.
5. When you're good, use a size to time equivalence to match the portion selected to the right time range